# Can I pass a file to Popen and still have it run asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess

I have a Django based server and I'm calling a script which does a bunch of work. This needs to be asynchronous so I'm using Popen. However for debugging I want to redirect stdout and stderr from PIPE to a file. Will this affect the asynchronous performance?

How should I make sure the file opens and closes properly when the python script itself is already done (and has made a return call.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen` runs asynchronously by default.

The `Popen` object can be stored and queried later.

```
p = subproccess.Popen(executable)

# continue with other work

p.poll() # returns None if p is still running, returncode otherwise
p.terminate() # closes the process forcefully

p.wait() # freezes the execution until process finishes - makes it synchronous
```

All that is needed is to store `p` somewhere until its status has to be checked, e.g. in a global list of started processes, if there is no better place.

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to be how to open a file, give it to `Popen` and then close the file when the process is finished, without keeping any references.

This can be simply done with a thread:

```
def run_process(executable, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=f).wait()

Thread(target=run_process, args=(executable, filename)).start()
```

Run it and forget about it. `run_process` will freeze until the process finishes and then it will close the file, but that all happens in a different thread.

**Note:** you may or may not care about what happens to the thread or to the process if they are not finished when the django process finishes.

For handling that, you might create a more complex thread which you would remember and stop when before django exits; it may also close the process or wait for it to finish...

Comment: I know it runs async by default, I meant, if I do stdout=f where f is a python file object, what happens if python leaves the file's frame of reference while the subprocess is still running?

Comment: @DylanLawrence Ah that! The file will remain open until you close it (don't use `with open(...)` though). On the other hand, you should keep the file reference somewehre, so that you can close it later.

Comment: So the one problem with that, is this is a web facing application so this script is handling clients and the subprocess call is basically "fire and forget." If I don't keep the variable, will the os handle cleanup?

Comment: That's great, thanks. Do I need to care what happens to the thread? If I don't do anything special in code it'll just clean itself up right?

Comment: @DylanLawrence If the thread's `daemon` flag is `False` (the default), the main thread will not exit until all those threads finish. That may be exactly what you want, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how asynchronous your program needs to be. Writes to stdout go to the operating system's file cache which is normally fast but may wait from time to time as data is flushed to the disk. Normally that's not a problem.

Since stdout is not a console, it will do buffered writes and that can be a problem if the program hits a non-standard error that skips flushing the pipe. The buffering can also delay what is in the file so for instance an external program cat'ing the file may not see logs right away.

The parent process should close its view of the file after starting the child and the operating system will take care of closing the file when the process terminates.

```
with open('stdout', 'w') as out, open('stderr', 'w') as err:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['myprog'], stdout=out, stderr=err)
```

Comment: Ok, so using `with` won't hold up the python script's execution at all?

Comment: The parent script? No, it runs at full speed. You passed the file handle to the child when it was started and the parent is now completely out of the loop. The child writes go straight to the operating system's file cache.

Comment: @tdelaney Shouldn't the `file.close()` called at the end of the `with` block affect the file?

Comment: @zvone - no, it closes the file in the parent but it remains open in the child.

Comment: @tdelaney That is nice. In that case, this is better than my solution ;)